# Is it possible to have a link that always opens a new tab in 'normal browsing mode', even if clicked from incognito?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

Is it possible to create a weblink on a page that will always open in 'normal' mode, even if the user was on the page in incognito mode?

Comment: I sure hope not...

Comment: Would that not defeat the whole point of Incognito mode?

Comment: No! why would you even do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be possible in a browser extension using, for example, [chrome. windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) which can open a window in an incognito or normal window. It may not be possible in all browsers, but TamperMonkey, GreaseMonkey & friends would be worth checking out for that possibility.